# Find machine where a SQL command was run from

Tags: sql-server

I have a rogue program updating a table in my SQL Server database every few minutes, I can see the transactions in the `fn_dblog` table.

Can anyone tell me how I can trace these back to a specific machine using this `fn_dblog` or some other means?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a trigger and check the data using `@@spid` from `sys.dm_exec_sessions`.

If your system isn't that busy, you could also use profiler.